# Ajax sends data multiple times

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, voting

I made a simple Ajax vote script for the posts of users: + 1 and -1. Everything works fine, but sometimes with one click for some reason the data sent +3, +6, -2 etc. I made a screenshot of Chrome developer tool. It is seen that that one click is called PHP script multiple times. dot.gif - the buzy animation while data sending.[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="raitings/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$(function() {$(".vote").click(function() {

var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
var parent = $(this);

if(name=='down')
{
$(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="raitings/dot.gif" align="absmiddle">');
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "raitings/down_vote.php", data: dataString, dataType : "html", cache: false, success: function(html)
   { parent.html(html);}
 });
}
else
{
$(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="raitings/dot.gif" align="absmiddle">');
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "raitings/up_vote.php", data: dataString, dataType : "html", cache: false, success: function(html)
   { parent.html(html);
  }  });
}
return false;
    });
});
</script>

<?php
echo "<div class=\"box1\"><div class=\"up\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"vote\" title=\"+ 1\" alt=\"+ 1\" id=".$row["id"]." name=\"up\">".$up."</a></div>"
."<div class=\"down\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"vote\" title=\"- 1\" alt=\"- 1\"  id=".$row["id"]." name=\"down\">".$down."</a></div></div>\n";
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information whether this page loads multiple time in the same container or not. it seems like the click event got registered multiple times.

Comment: This is the old CMS PHP-Nuke. There is a module - guest book. I just inserted the above code in the index.php of the module for each post output.

Comment: I also had such problem when I was using jQuery .live() method, sometimes it is useful to use it together with .die(), if you have such situation, then take a look at .die().

Comment: Nikita, could you in my example to show how and where I should call .die()?

Answer (score 1):

When user have voted you should disable your controls. So Just add some blocking flag (variable, cookie, etc.):

```
$(function() {
var isUserVoted = false;
$(".vote").click(function() {
   if (isUserVoted) {
       return false;
   }

   isUserVoted = true;
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   var name = $(this).attr("name");
   var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
   var parent = $(this);

   if(name=='down') {
      $(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="raitings/dot.gif" align="absmiddle">');
      $.ajax({type: "POST", url: "raitings/down_vote.php", data: dataString, dataType : "html", cache: false, success: function(html)
   { parent.html(html);}
      });
   } else {
      $(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="raitings/dot.gif" align="absmiddle">');
      $.ajax({type: "POST", url: "raitings/up_vote.php", data: dataString, dataType : "html", cache: false, success: function(html) { parent.html(html);
  }  });
   }
   return false;
});
});
```

Comment: The whole point is to give for a user the opportunity to vote in several post on the same page and in your code it is impossible.

Comment: Just create flags (some map, etc) for all votes. You should not send any data to server if user has already voted. Also searching for DOM elements by class name is the most slow one.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand how to do it. Not skilled in JS.

Answer (score -1):

Instead on jquery click event try to write onclick="function_name();" for a href..

for e.g. ...